# an exercise in ≠of?

Tags: vocabulary

Does the word "exercise" in this sentence means something different because it is followed by the preposition "in" instead of "of". I've looked the word up on merriam-webster but i could only find examples of "exercise" followed by "of"

Here's a sentence:

"Achieving compliance is an exercise **in** purpose, not power"

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use or exert something within your control, that's an exercise *of* the object: an exercise of strength, power, duty, stock options. From [Merriam-Webster Online](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/exercise):

> 1 a : the act of bringing into play or realizing in action : use <the *exercise* **of** self-control>

When you perform a lesson or other marked practice, that's an exercise *in* the object: an exercise in arithmetic, compromise, futility.

> 3 : something performed or practiced in order to develop, improve, or display a specific capability or skill <arithmetic *exercises*> <vocal *exercises*>
>
> 4 : a performance or activity having a strongly marked secondary or ulterior aspect <party politics has always been an *exercise* **in** compromise — H. S. Ashmore>

In your example, the use of *in* emphasizes that it's a deliberate practice of purpose (achievement) rather than power (control).